# Matching by array elements in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to construct quite a non-trivial (as it seems to be now) query in Elasticsearch.
Suppose I have a couple of entities, each with an array element, consisting of strings:

```
1). ['A', 'B']
2). ['A', 'C']
3). ['A', 'E']
4). ['A']
```

Mappings for array element is as follows (using dynamic templates):

```
{
  "my_array_of_strings": {
    "path_match": "stringArray*",
    "mapping": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

Json representation of entity looks like this:

```
{
  "stringArray": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ]
}
```

Then I have user input:
    ['A', 'B', 'C'].

What I want to achieve is to find entities which contain only elements specified in input - expected results are:
['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A'] but NOT ['A', 'E'] (because 'E' is not present in user input).

Can this scenario be implemented with Elasticsearch?

**UPDATE:**
Apart from the solution with using the scripts - which should work nicely, but will most likely slow down the query considerably in case when there are many records that match - I have devised another one. Below I will try to explain its main idea, without code implementation.

One considerable condition that I failed to mention (and which might have given other users valuable hint) is that arrays consist of enumerated elements, i.e. there are finite number of such elements in array. This allows to flatten such array into separate field of an entity.

Lets say there are 5 possible values: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'. Each of these values is a boolean field - true if it is empty (i.e. array version would contain this element ) and false otherwise.
Then each of the entities could be rewritten as follows:

```
1).
A = true
B = true
C = false
D = false
E = false

2).
A = true
B = false
C = true
D = false
E = false

3).
A = true
B = false
C = false
D = false
E = true

4).
A = true
B = false
C = false
D = false
E = false
```

With the user input of ['A', 'B', 'C'] all I would need to do is:
**a)** take all possible values (['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']) and subtract from them user input -> result will be ['D', 'E'];
**b)** find records where each of resulting elements is false, i.e. 'D = false AND E = false'.

This would give records 1, 2 and 4, as expected. I am still experimenting with the code implementation of this approach, but so far it looks quite promising. It has yet to be tested, but I think this might perform faster, and be less resource demanding, than using scripts in query.

To optimize this a little bit further, it might be possible not to provide fields which will be 'false' at all, and modify the previous query to 'D = not exists AND E = not exists' - result should be the same.

Comment: You can create a custom analyzer during mapping and then search each word (character before a comma) separately.

Comment: Could you provide the mapping of the doc, please? It's easier to provide feedback on details (based on: is the above string values '[A, E]' or arrays of strings ['A', 'E']?). I assume ['A', 'E'] but specifying it in the question allows for more clarity...

Comment: @Calle, thanks for pointing this out. I will update the question

Comment: @MobasherFasihy thanks for the suggestion, can you please provide an example? This is an array of strings, not a string - so I do not see any use case for custom analyzer.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html), This is how it looks

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "name": [
                  "A",
                  "B",
                  "C"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "if(user_input.containsAll(doc['name'].values)){return true;}",
                "params": {
                  "user_input": [
                    "A",
                    "B",
                    "C"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This `groovy script` is checking if the list contains anything apart from `['A', 'B', 'C']` and returns false if it does, so it wont return `['A', 'E']`. It is simply checking for **sublist** match. This script might take couple of seconds. You would need to enable `dynamic scripting`, also syntax might be different for `ES 2.x`, let me know if it does not work.

**EDIT 1**

I have put both conditions inside `filter` only. First only those documents that have either *A, B or C* are returned, and then script is applied on only those documents, so this would be faster than the previous one. More on [filter ordering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filter_order.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea, I will certainly give it a try! However, I have read that scripting slows down queries considerably. In my case there might be up to 10k results returned, so running a script on each of the result might be quite slow. I have devised another solution, which I will try to implement as well - I will update my post

Comment: Yes, you are right, scripts do slow down queries, but It should not be more than few seconds(4-5 max, I am guessing), but let us know about your solution too, In the meantime I will also think about something else, maybe we can do something during analysis phase.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it faster than the previous one. pls have a look.

Comment: That's a good addition, I was also thinking about suggesting it. Btw, 'do_not_return' variable in groovy script could be renamed to 'is_included' or something like this - just for better readability.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer, I have also added `break` to avoid further computation once we find the undesired element.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 in your script you should make the `list_to_check` a parameter to the script instead of hardcoding it inside the script. Moreover, in groovy there's a very simple way to compare two lists/arrays, i.e. `doc['name'].values.equals(list_to_check)` (you just need to make sure both lists are sorted.). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Val, Thanks for the comments. You are right about `param`, actually I just  wrote the script for demo, I will edit the answer, but regarding **comparing** lists, I think both OP wants 'sublist match' and not exact match so equals wont work, correct me If I am wrong

Comment: Probably, but the initial question still states "exactly equals", which I think is wrong, but we'll see. Keep the lead on that!

Comment: Little bit simpler: `"script": "user_input.containsAll(doc['name'].values)"`

Comment: @SergeyShuvalov Thanks a lot for that, my bad :)

Answer (score -1):

In same case for me I have done the follow steps:

First of all I have deleted the index to redefine `analyzer/settings` with `sense plugin`.

```
DELETE my_index
```

Then I have defined custom analyzer `for my_index`

```
PUT my_index
{
  "index" : {
    "analysis" : {
        "tokenizer" : {
            "comma" : {
                "type" : "pattern",
                "pattern" : ","
            }
        },
        "analyzer" : {
            "comma" : {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "comma"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have defined mapping properties inside my code, but you can also do that with sense. both of them are same.

```
PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
        "properties" : {
            "conduct_days" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "comma"
            }
        }
}
```

Then For testing do these bellow steps:

```
PUT /my_index/my_type/1
{
    "coduct_days" : "1,2,3"
}

PUT /my_index/my_type/2
{
    "conduct_days" : "3,4"
}

PUT /my_index/my_type/3
{
    "conduct_days" : "1,6"
}

GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {"match_all": {}}
}

GET /my_index/_search
{
    "filter": {
       "or" : [
          { 
            "term": {
               "coduct_days": "6"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
               "coduct_days": "3"
            }
          }
       ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... does this work in you case? Using the query you specified, no records could be found. But more surprisingly, it does not find anything using any combination of "conduct_days" - I've tried "1", "2" and "3" in a single query (which should definitely return 1st record), and still nothing.

Comment: Yeah, In a case with me, it is working. `conduct_days` has like `1,2,3,4,5` values, and input data may contain like `1`, or like `1,2,4` and I can search separately for each of input values.