# Elastic match documents containing all values in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents like the ones bellow in Elastic. Each document has some information and all mandatory permissions to access the document.

When I query, I would like to pass all user permissions and receive matched documents but am having difficulties with the query.

The documents:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "permissions": ["a", "d"]
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "permissions": ["a"]
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "permissions": ["a", "b"]
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "permissions": ["a", "c"]
}
```

This is the closest I got:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "tags.keyword": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "tags.keyword": "b"
          }
        },
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": doc.tags.length
    }
  }
}
// Result are documents with id's 2 and 3.
```

I tried extending the `"minimum_should_match"` with the `"script"` but without success (apparently it does not support it):

```
"script" : {
    "script" : {
        "inline": "doc['permissions'].length",
        "lang": "painless"
     }
}
```

In an example above, with passed permission array `["a", "b", "c"]`, the output should be documents with id's 2, 3 and 4. `["a"]` matches only document with id 2.

EDIT: Additional information
A document has up to 5 permissions, as well as the users, but the set of permissions is quite big (500+), so I am searching for a generic query. The data can also be transformed.

I am using Elastic 7.6
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient way to achieve your expected result, but apart from the below search query, you can even get your result using scripting, please refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34881682/10348758) to know that.

You can use [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field.

Adding a working example with index data(taken the same as that given in question), index mapping, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "permissions": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "permissions": [
                  "a",
                  "b",
                  "c"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "permissions": [
                  "d"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "stof_64081578",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "id": 2,
      "permissions": [
        "a"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "stof_64081578",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "id": 3,
      "permissions": [
        "a",
        "b"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "stof_64081578",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "id": 4,
      "permissions": [
        "a",
        "c"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The first document is retrieved incorrectly. Permission "d" is required which user does not have (has a, b, c). The binding expression should be AND instead of OR, which terms does behind the scenes. Also saw I messed up the first example. Id's 2- 4 should be returned. Edited. P.S.: Some people need sleep ;).

Comment: @JakaKonda please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: @JakaKonda did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: It works for a specific case so it won't work generalized. A user always has 5 permissions, with about 500 different values (they aren't permissions, but are used for easier understanding). And the document always has up to 5 permissions.

Comment: @JakaKonda as far as I know, there is no generic way to achieve your required results. Apart from the above search query you can even use script